# Get rid of mutable `let`

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

For example, I need to cache last task outside of the loop (redux-saga).

```js
export default function* () {
  let lastTask;
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(someActions);
    // some conditions there
    if (lastTask) {
      yield cancel(lastTask);
    }
    lastTask = yield fork(send(action));
  }
}
```

What pattern should I use there to make it in a functional immutable way without `let`?

Comment: Why do you want to? This looks like non-pure code to me anyway, with all the "actions" and async stuff.

Comment: @Thomas That is vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: @Thomas It's almost copy/paste of redux-saga's [docs example](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#notes-4)

Comment: I meant "pure" as in "pure functional": not depending on external state, outputs depending solely on inputs. But maybe the whole discussion of pureness is besides the point. My question remains: what's wrong with the `let` here?

Comment: @Thomas redux-saga provides a pure effects library. `take` and `fork` is completely pure and return descriptors instead of evaluations. See https://runkit.com/embed/znqi5w7s9q43

Comment: > My question remains: what's wrong with the let here?

@Thomas, In fact my team just tries to avoid `let` with eslint. But anyway, sagas will execute it with `next` iteration, which become impure in this way (I hope I understand it correctly)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have the generator recursively `yield*` itself:

```
function* gen (lastTask) {
  const action = yield take(someActions);
  // some conditions there
  if (lastTask) {
    yield cancel(lastTask);
  }
  const nextLastTask = yield fork(send(action));
  yield* gen(nextLastTask);
}
export default gen;
```

But note that nothing in your original code (or this code) involves *mutation* - the problem with `let` is that it permits *reassignment*, which is somewhat similar, but not the same thing. (Best to avoid mutation *and* reassignment, if possible, as long as the code remains easy to read)

Make sure the consumer calls `gen` with no arguments, of course.

Comment: What is the difference between `x = {foo: 2}` and `x.foo = 2` when given `let x = {foo: 1}` in the context of functional programming (i.e. referential transparency)?

Comment: Assignment mutates the scope.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Looks very good. But it seems that recursion's is never cleared. I think it's not very nice.

Comment: @heleg That's identical to the behavior your current code, which I thought you wanted - your generator never completes because of its `while(true)`. If you wanted logic to break out of the generator, can you describe it? It's not present in your question

Comment: @CertainPerformance Don't you have a memory leak in your example? There's a new scope every iteration and garbage collector can't clean it, because this recursion will never be resolved. That's what I meant.